# How to Hide URL parameters with php redirect

Tags: php, html

I read this article: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/hiding-url-parameters-php-redirect-33163.html
which explains how to but I'm don't understand how you redirect with the header as they say in there.

For storing in sessions this is code I use

```
session_start();  
function input_val($key, $remember = true) {  //use input_val('nameofinputfield')as value to be able to store in session
    $value='';
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$key])) {
       $value = $_REQUEST[$key];
       //Store value in session if remember = true 
       if($remember) {
         $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
       }
       return $value;
    } else {
      //Return session data
      return isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Do you start session in all of your page with `session_start();` ?

Comment: yes, the problem is I'm using the get method to pass the variables and so I'm trying to find a way to hide the variables from the URL, and so it explains in that article how to do it with redirect

Comment: Please be a littlebit more specific. what do you do not know. how to redirect?

Comment: From what page you want to redirect to what page and with what parameters?

Comment: Well yes, according to the article I have to do it with the header('Location: http://example.com/script2.php'); ?> but I tried doing that and it didn't work

Comment: please post your whole code of script1.php and script2.php

Comment: Is just a form that when you click submit it passes the variables to the confimartion page, but I don't want the variables to be seen in the URL, I know that by using the post method this wouldn't be a problem but Im using get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, you want to pass a username and email parameter from your script1.php to script2.php. If you are using `POST` method, in the URL the parameters won't show, and you can access your passed variables through `$_POST` global variable. But, if you want to use `GET` method for any reason, or you want to store data in `$_SESSION` you can do this.

You can try to use this in your script2.php:

```
session_start();
if (count($_GET)) {
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
}
//At here, you can access all of your parameters from $_SESSOION variable
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: This works perfect thank you. However, I still have a little problem, before your solution I was dealing with checkboxes in the following way: on script1 I have <input type="checkbox" name="checks" id="checks"  <?php echo (($checks=='on') ? 'checked' : '');?> > on script 2 <?php if(isset($_GET['checks'])){

print "✓";

}else{

 echo "<input type='checkbox'    disabled >"; 

}?> with your solution on script2 the state of the checkbox is not visible

Comment: If a checkbox does not checked, then that wont be in your `$_POST` or `$_GET` array. So, you need to check it manually.

Comment: Also, add a value to your checkbox, `<input type="checkbox" name="checks" id="checks" value="1" <?php echo (($checks=='on') ? 'checked="checked"' : '');?> />`

Comment: I there any way you think I could pass the checkbox value

Comment: No. It's only passed, if it's checked. But you can add an `<input type="hidden" name="nameofyourcheckbox_test" value="nameofyourcheckbox" />` and then the php side, you can check, is that `$_GET["nameofyourcheckbox_test"]` is checked or not with `if (isset($_GET["nameofyourcheckbox_test"]))` or something like that. It's hard to explain in comment. Create another question for it.

Comment: I have to wait seven days to ask again, are you saying that in script 1 I have <input type="hidden" name="nameofyourcheckbox_test" value="nameofyourcheckbox" /> and the on script 2 if (isset($_GET["nameofyourcheckbox_test"])) so if the box was checked it would display in a checked state on script 2?

Comment: This whole thing is based on, what is on your form. If it is a static form, and there are several checkboxes with unique names, then forget this whole thing, and after `foreach` loop test it manually. `if (isset($_GET["checkboxname"])) { $_SESSION["checkboxname"] = 1;} else { $_SESSION["checkboxname"] = 0; }` My hidden solution in that case, if you are building your form dynamically so hidden will passed, and base on it's value, you can check the value of checkbox, becuse you will know the name of checkbox. As i sad, it's complicated to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it as simple as I can, it's not that difficult. 
When a user is in a session with the php he stores a little blob of text in the browser, this text is like a user ID that lasts until he close his browser. The php script can tell and extract information from the server, like parameters, by knowing his ID. This is not a cross-server feature though and it isn't persistent, unlike  cookies, the expiration on the sessions are normally short and they expire when the user closes his browser.

Also it is recommended not to use it to store Get information like Page number, because it can't be re-referenced.